# Compact letter display for kruskal- wallis Dunn post-hoc test

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I am performing kruskal-wallis tests on. I would like to add a compact letter display of the result to:

1. A table of the mean, sd, Z stat, P value, + letters
2. A Graph of the results with the compact letters displayed

There is a wealth of knowledge on how to do this after a TukeyHSD, but I can't figure it out using other models post-hocs i.e. Kruskal-Wallis Dunn test, welch ANOVA pairwise.t.test etc. I have thought about doing it manually, but it is not working.

This is what I have so far:

```
data <- iris
kruskal <- kruskal.test(Petal.Width ~ Species, data = data)
kruskal_ph <- dunnTest(Petal.Width ~ Species,
                  data=data,
                  method="bonferroni")

#Make CLD here ....



#OR


#First make comparisons table and mannually insert letters. E.g.

pvalue <- kruskal_ph[[2]][, "P.adj"]
    hi <- kruskal_ph[[2]][,"Comparison"] %>%
              as.data.frame()
      hi <- hi %>%
          rename(hi, comps = .) %>%
          separate(comps, c("group1","group2"))
      comparisons <- cbind(hi, pvalue)
    comparisons$Sig <- comparisons$Sig
    comparisons$Sig[comparisons$pvalue > 0.05] <- "ns"
    comparisons$Sig[comparisons$pvalue <= 0.05] <- "*"
    comparisons$Sig[comparisons$pvalue <= 0.01] <- "**"
comparisons

# Make CLD from comparisons here


# Add to a summary table (how?) and graph?

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The `agricolae` package may be useful in this scenario:

```
library(agricolae)
kruskal_cld <- kruskal(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, group=TRUE, p.adj="bonferroni")$groups
cld <- as.data.frame(kruskal_cld)
group_df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Petal.Width), sd = sd(Petal.Width)) 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  geom_text(data = group_df, aes(label = cld$group, y = mean + sd, x = Species), vjust = -0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://schmidtpaul.github.io/dsfair_quarto/summaryarticles/compactletterdisplay.html

Comment: The *agricolae* documentation says, `Post hoc test is using the criterium Fisher's least significant difference`.  I'm not sure that's the most appropriate post-hoc test.  It's easy enough to use the *FSA* or *PMCMRplus* packages for Dunn, Conover, or Nemenyi tests.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use package "agricolae"

Then change your code to this:

```
print(kruskal(data$Petal.Width, data$Species, group=TRUE))
```

The output will then give you a compact letter display. Unsure what the test it uses is however.

Comment: `Unsure what the test it uses is however`....  That doesn't give one much confidence in the approach...